# Moving of Big query Datasets between data locations

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to move data of some big query data sets from one data location to another without losing any in-flight data.I understand GCP supports data transfers between data sets but this requires multiple data sets to be created . Ex: To change data location of Dataset "A" , we  need to create an empty Data set "B" (in the intended data location) and copy data set "A" to "B". Now, once the copy is done , we need to delete "A" , and , again create an empty data set "A"(in the intended data location) and copy from "B" to "A" and then delete "B". is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered chaining together the commands to move the data and then delete it in Bash?

```bash
bq cp datasetname.oldtablename datasetname.newtablename && bq rm -f datasetname.oldtablename
```

`bq rm -f` doesn't ask for confirmation when deleting.

As the 'bq cp' command returns a non-0 (false) exit status, the 'bq rm' command will not execute if the copy fails because of the `&&` (and) operator between the commands.